# Remove Nodeclipse Console from Console View

Tags: eclipse, console, nodeclipse

The checkbox in the Nodeclipse settings to enable the Nodeclipse console has no effect on removing the console from the console view. I launch several applications in Eclipse (Neon but this problem has been around for a while) and when terminating them, the Nodeclipse Console can appear forcing selection of other consoles. I'd like to get rid of the Nodeclipse console in the console view so I can hit the red terminate button and the XX button to move from one application to the other to close them. Ideally Eclipse should add a terminate all option, but until then not having the Nodeclipse console would simplify matters. Since they have a checkbox to enable this console, perhaps making it work (e.g., unchecked would disable/remove it from the Console view) would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodeclipse Console was meant for some extra information about Nodeclipse plugin's operation. The checkbox in the Nodeclipse settings would only for enable/disable output into the Nodeclipse console.

Debug View (2nd on Nodeclipse perspective) is great to see all lauch Node processes and terminate all or one selected.

Please raise an issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/ and reference this question.